# confused about what my service method should return

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model, service-layer, domain-model

I have 2 domain classes: User and Role. 1 User can have 1 or more Roles.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private boolean lockFlag;
   private List<Role> rolesList;
   // getters and setters 
}

public class Role implements Serializable {
   private int roleId;
   private String description;
   // getters and setters
}
```

In my service layer I have a method to login a user into the system. This method receives 3 arguments: `String username`, `String password`, `int roleId` and it throws an exception `UserServiceException` if an error occurs.

```
public void login(String username, String password, int roleId) throws UserServiceException;
```

The service method retrieve the User domain class along with associated Roles:

```
User user = userDAO.getUserById(username);
```

The service method retrieve the Role domain class:

```
Role role = roleDAO.getRoleById(roleId);
```

The service method perform no. of checks. Assuming all checks are passed, service method needs to tell its caller that the login was successful and send the `user` object and the `role` object. That's where I am confused how to send them. I have come up with some options:

---

### OPTION 1:

Change the service method signature to return object of `User` domain class:

```
public User login(String username, String password, int roleId) throws UserServiceException;
```

Change the `User` domain class to add one more property `currentRole` which is of `Role` class type:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private boolean lockFlag;
   private List<Role> rolesList;
   private Role currentRole;
   // getters and setters 
}
```

In my service method set the `currentRole` property of `user` object to the `role` object before sending the `user` object:

```
user.setCurrentRole(role);
return user;
```

---

### OPTION 2:

Instead of changing the `User` domain class, create a DTO which resembles the `User` domain class + one more property `currentRole` which is of `Role` class type:

```
public class UserModelDTO implements Serializable {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private boolean lockFlag;
   private List<Role> rolesList;
   private Role currentRole;
   // getters and setters 
}
```

Change the service method signature to return object of `UserModelDTO` class:

```
public UserModelDTO login(String username, String password, int roleId) throws UserServiceException;
```

In my service method create an object of `UserModelDTO` class and send it:

```
UserModelDTO userModelDTO = new UserModelDTO();
userModelDTO.setUsername(user.getUsername());
userModelDTO.setPassword(user.getPassword());
userModelDTO.setLockFlag(user.getLockFlag());
userModelDTO.setRolesList(user.getRolesList());
userModelDTO.setCurrentRole(role);
return userModelDTO;
```

---

### OPTION 3:

Create a DTO which has 1 property `user` of `User` class type and 1 property `role` of `Role` class type:

```
public class UserRoleModelDTO implements Serializable {
   private User user;
   private Role role;
   // getters and setters 
}
```

Change the service method signature to return object of `UserRoleModelDTO` class:

```
public UserRoleModelDTO login(String username, String password, int roleId) throws UserServiceException;
```

In my service method create an object of `UserRoleModelDTO` class and send it:

```
UserRoleModelDTO userRoleModelDTO = new UserRoleModelDTO();
userRoleModelDTO.setUser(user);
userRoleModelDTO.setRole(role);
return userRoleModelDTO;
```

---

### OPTION 4:

Change the service method signature to return a `Map`:

```
public Map login(String username, String password, int roleId) throws UserServiceException;
```

In my service method create a `Map` and send it:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("USER_DOMAIN", user);
map.put("ROLE_DOMAIN", role);
return map;
```

---

### OPTION 5:

**No link to domain classes.**

Create a `RoleModelDTO` which resembles the `Role` class type. 
Create a `UserModelDTO` which resembles the `User` class type. 
In `UserModelDTO`, the property `rolesList` will refer to List of `RoleModelDTO` type. 
In `UserModelDTO`, add one more property `currentRole` which is of `RoleModelDTO` class type:

```
public class RoleModelDTO implements Serializable {
   private int roleId;
   private String description;
   // getters and setters 
}

public class UserModelDTO implements Serializable {
   private String username;
   private String password;
   private boolean lockFlag;
   private List<RoleModelDTO> rolesList;
   private RoleModelDTO currentRole;
   // getters and setters 
}
```

Change the service method signature to return object of `UserModelDTO` class:

```
public UserModelDTO login(String username, String password, int roleId) throws UserServiceException;
```

In my service method create an object of `UserModelDTO` class and send it:

```
RoleModelDTO roleModelDTO = new RoleModelDTO();
roleModelDTO.setRoleId(role.getRoleId());
roleModelDTO.setDescription(role.getDescription());

List<RoleModelDTO> roleModelDTOList = new ArrayList<RoleModelDTO>();
for (Role role1 : user.getRolesList()) {
    RoleModelDTO roleModelDTO1 = new RoleModelDTO();
    roleModelDTO1.setRoleId(role1.getRoleId());
    roleModelDTO1.setDescription(role1.getDescription());
    roleModelDTOList.add(roleModelDTO1);
}

UserModelDTO userModelDTO = new UserModelDTO();
userModelDTO.setUsername(user.getUsername());
userModelDTO.setPassword(user.getPassword());
userModelDTO.setLockFlag(user.getLockFlag());
userModelDTO.setRolesList(roleModelDTOList);
userModelDTO.setCurrentRole(roleModelDTO);
return userModelDTO;
```

---

Which of the option should I go with? Is there any other option which makes the most sense? If yes please do share.

Some questions:

Does 1 service method should always return 1 domain class? In case of wanting to return more than 1 domain class, should we build a relationship between them?

Regarding Option 1, does it make sense to change a domain class to include something your caller (controller) need?

Regarding Options 2, 3 &4, does it make sense to return anything other than a domain class from the service method?

Which options might be breaking a design pattern?

## UPDATE 1

I thought about another option which I have added as 5th option. This option sends a DTO but that DTO has no link to Domain model classes. Interesting concept.

Please reply about my question. I am in kind of a limbo and need some experienced developers guidelines to move me forward.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect the role to be returned? Assumption would be that the user has the corresponding role assigned, wouldn't it?

Comment: On the Controller side I need to store the specific Role which was used by the User to login in session.

Comment: In that case I would go for a class like "public class AuthenticatedUser { User user; Role authenticatedRole}" which returns the corresponding fields as a composite.

Comment: Would you refer to `AuthenticatedUser` as a DTO or a domain class?

Comment: If you need it only to get the information to your frontend/controller I would call it DTO

Comment: yes that's the only purpose. Basically it would be stored in session and I would pass it as a the 1st parameter of all methods in the service classes. Would you advise storing it in a different package than where the domain classes are stored? Or should it use the same package? For e.g. if domain classes are in `com.myapp.model.domain` package then should this `AuthenticatedUser` be store in the same package? or should it be in a package in service layer like `com.myapp.model.service.dto`?